# How to replace spaces in text at a specified position in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column called Test for saving the char eg.

```
A:Hi B: 13/06/2022 C:Peter
```

and then  use string_split() to extract the B

```
declare @test varchar(100) = replace('A:Hi C:Peter B: 13/06/2022',' ','')

select * from string_split(@test,' ')
where [value] like 'B%'
```

After code result

```
A:HiB:13/06/2022C:Peter
```

Expect result:

```
A:Hi B:13/06/2022 C:Peter
```

How to remove the space between B and date of Test column ? 
I tried to used `REPLACE,ltrim,rtrim`, but it is not working any suggest or idea? Thank you.

Comment: Replace should work, show us your code.

Comment: `How to remove the space between B and date of Test `. The sample text you shown on top has a colon ` :` and space between `B:` and the date (`A:Hi B: 13/06/2022 C:Peter`). But in the sample query, you don't have a space there `'A:Hi B:13/06/2022 C:Peter'`. Please clarify exactly what do you want

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hi Squirrel,Dale K. thank your reply and suggestion, i have  updated the query in question.

Comment: What are you even using `string_split` if you want the complete original string, just with spaces removed? Why not just `replace('A:Hi C:Peter B: 13/06/2022', 'B: ','B:');`?

Comment: Then your question is unclear, your desired result doesn't require `string_split` - please clarify.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, thank your advise, i think you have englighten my question....thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @test varchar(100) = replace('A:Hi C:Peter B: 13/06/2022','B: ','B:')

select * from string_split(@test,' ')
where [value] like 'B%'
```